# friendly-recovery error running apt (upgrade, dist-upgrade or autoremove)

Tags: apt, grub2

When running apt, either upgrade, dist-upgrade or autoremove, I get an error concerning friendly-recovery and grub. I've been looking around but can't find a solution. It seems to update / install other packages fine.

I've included the command, output and the relevant files from what I understand. If any more information can help please let me know.

Hope someone can help!

Command and output:

```
> sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up friendly-recovery (0.2.38ubuntu1.1) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
dpkg: error processing package friendly-recovery (--configure):
 installed friendly-recovery package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 friendly-recovery
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

contents of /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

contents of /etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"
# disable grub os prober that might find other OS installs.
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Answer (score 0):

comment in /etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg the entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity"` out. `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: Added a # in front of that line in 50-curtin..., ran the command, same error sadly.

Comment: I oversee the same is in /etc/default/grub.  Remove maybe-ubiquity between''   "

Comment: Made the row in /etc/default/grub say `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`, reran `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`, same error.